# Certificate specified in header with openUI5 for SSL connection

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, odata, sapui5

I am trying to figure out how can I connect to Odata with ssl certificate authentification. We are using it with openUI5. Application is running as mobile application.

**I tried several connection types on mobile device:**

- http is working good
- https with optional certificate works good
- https with required certificate **Cannot access data**

**I also tried several connection types from browser:**

- http is working good
- https with optional certificate works good
- https with required certificate **Can access data**

So i was thinking that when I specify the certificate inside of header when creating the oModel inside of the app, it would work. But I don't know how to specify it correctly.

I tried to access certificates using this class: 
https://help.sap.com/saphelp_smp235/helpdata/en/94/78b8de6c9110149d2cd7d1ca6ec99d/content.htm

It looks like this:

```
  var certStore = listAvailableCertificatesFromFileSystem();
  var certPaths = certStore.listAvailableCertificatesFromFileSystem("/sdcard/", "p12");
  var cert = certStore.getSignedCertificateFromFile(certPaths[0], servicePassword);
  var headersMap = [];
  headersMap["SSL_CLIENT_CERT"] = cert.signedCertificate; // here I dont know how could I access it.


 this.oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(this.serviceUrl, {
            user: serviceLogin,
            password: servicePassword,
            withCredentials: true,
            disableHeadRequestForToken: false,
            useBatch: false,
            headers: headersMap  // here i specify the header...
        });
```

Thank you

Comment: Define 'doesn't work well'.

Comment: @EJP very constructive... 
page could not be loadbecause of  ERROR_SSL_PROTOCOL